# Change global variable according the value in Settings bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c

My project loads a settings bundle which preserves several host addresses, a variable representing host address changed by user's preference, and in app that i set host address as global variable through `#define` keyword.

The variable defined by `#define` can't be changed, so what about `extern`?

Now I want to change the global variable according the value in Settings bundle, how can i implement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @trojanfoe I've tag the question `objective-c`.

Comment: That's language; not platform.

Comment: @trojanfoe :) i added tag `ios`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a singleton object containing the settings, exposed as properties, would be better, however it should just be a case of overwriting what you have with the values from `NSUserDefaults`.

So assume you have `Settings.h`:

```
extern NSString *hostAddress1;
extern NSString *hostAddress2;
extern NSString *hostAddress3;
```

and `Settings.m`:

```
NSString *hostAddress1 = nil;
NSString *hostAddress2 = nil;
NSString *hostAddress3 = nil;
```

then they can be set as simply as:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
hostAddress1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"hostAddress1"];
hostAddress2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"hostAddress2"];
hostAddress3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"hostAddress3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`#define`s are used by the preprocessor only, so a tl;dr answer would be **no**.

But, in a more detailed answer, you could do something like trojanfoe's answer. And you still could complement it by changing your existing `#define` to use those global variables:

`#define SERVER_HOST hostAddress1`